# Parsing xml in eclipse

Tags: java, xml-parsing, google-api

I'm writing code in java and trying to parse the xml from this URL:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=30.606595,33.546753&destination=30.657406,33.712234&sensor=false

This URL is belong to google API, which takes 2 points (src, dest) and return the route between them in xml.

When i debug the program with eclipse, it runs perfect. but when i run the code without debug, it returns an error. (when I put a breakpoint at the end of the function, the "dist" is null and i don't know why)
Any idea why it happens?

the code is

```
public double calcDist(Point p) //p=the src of the ride (the dest in the calculation)
    {
        String src = Double.toString(this.lati);
        src = src.concat(",");
        src = src.concat(Double.toString(this.longi));
        String dest = Double.toString(p.lati);
        dest = dest.concat(",");
        dest = dest.concat(Double.toString(p.longi));

    String dist=null;
    URL url = null;
    try 
    {
        url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin="+src+"&destination="+dest+"&sensor=false");

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = null;
        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = null;
        doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("leg");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) 
        {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            NodeList nodeList2 =node.getChildNodes();
            for (int j = 0; j < nodeList2.getLength(); j++) 
            {
                Node child = nodeList2.item(j);
                if (child.getNodeName().contentEquals("distance"))
                {
                    NodeList nodeList3 = child.getChildNodes();
                    for (int p1 = 0; p1 < nodeList3.getLength(); p1++) 
                    {
                        Node child2 = nodeList3.item(p1);
                        if (child2.getNodeName().contentEquals("text"))
                        {
                            Node tmp = child2.getFirstChild();
                            if (tmp != null) 
                                dist = child2.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ParserConfigurationException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (SAXException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    dist = dist.substring(0, dist.length()-3);
    return Double.parseDouble(dist);
}
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: it stops on the line
dist = dist.substring(0, dist.length()-3); (at the end)
because dist is null, and cant do the "substring" function so the program stoped

Comment: take a breakpoint at dist = child2.getFirstChild().getNodeValue(); and check if it is still null. Try instantiating dist = "";

Comment: i took a breakpoint on that command, and dist is "17 km", but again, if i run the program without stop in the middle, it returns null....
where do you want me to do dist = ""; ??

Answer (score 0):

instead of XML request json object (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=30.606595,33.546753&destination=30.657406,33.712234&sensor=false)and use a java library such as: http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide to convert it to a java object and pull whatever you need. XML is heavy in your case.

Comment: i used to use xml so thats why i chose to use xml, i dont know how to work with json. is there any way to solve my problem using xml?
thanx!

Answer (score -1):

I don't run the code. But it seems to me, after checking the XML file, that the distance comes in the format `17,0 km` out of the xml. After your substring it still remains `17,0`, but in Java and other langugages floating numbers using a dot. So this could be your error.

But it could be possible, that something with your parser is wrong.

You could use SAX-Parser API of Java for XML parsing, instead of the slow and unperformant DOM-parser.

BR

Comment: thanx for your answer, but when i put a breakpoint on the line  dist = dist.substring(0, dist.length'()-3); the "dist" parameter is NULL instead of "17.0 km" or even "17,0 km".... so i dont think that this is the problem.
BTW: when i debug it (command by command) the dist is "17.0 km" with a dot instead of comma.....